# yacal.js next/back button removes jquery event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, jquery-events

I am using [yacal.js](http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Basic-Lightweight-jQuery-Calendar-Plugin-Yacal.html) to build a calendar.

Here are the [javascript](http://wxrunning.com/tests/jquery.yacal.min.js) and the [css](http://wxrunning.com/tests/jquery.yacal.css) for yacal.js (its from my site because i couldn't find a cdn for it)

For my project, I am trying to make it so that when a user clicks on a date, an ajax request is sent to my php page with the date and my php page gets a row from the database with the matching date.

all of it works fine... but when I click the next/back button (the two buttons at the top of the calendar that change months) it removes my jQuery event:

`$("a.day").click(function() {`

why is this happening?

or what can I do to fix it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Calendar</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://wxrunning.com/tests/jquery.yacal.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="calendarTemplate"></div>

  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://wxrunning.com/tests/jquery.yacal.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("a.day").click(function() {
        showData(
          Number($(this).html()),
          $(this).parents("div.month").attr('class').replace('month m', ''),
          $(this).parents("div.month").children('h4').html().replace(/\D/g, '')

        );
      });
    });

    function showData(a, b, c) {
      a = (a < 10) ? '0' + a : a;
      b = (b < 10) ? '0' + b : b;
      alert('Day:' + a + ', Month:' + b + ', Year:' + c);
    }
    $('#calendarTemplate').yacal();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

notice that after you click the back or forward buttons a few times it doesn't alert anymore

Comment: Classical problem in JS DOM scripting. You overwrite the HTML content and don’t rebind the event listeners. The event listeners are lost if the corresponding elements are overwritten. Something that even [happened to Stack Overflow developers themselves](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254593/289905).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

You're binding the event on page load. But when the elements are removed and replaced by other elements(days), the event is unbound.

Bind the event using [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as

```
$("#calendarTemplate").on("click", "a.day", function() {
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#calendarTemplate").on("click", "a.day", function() {
    showData(
      Number($(this).html()),
      $(this).parents("div.month").attr('class').replace('month m', ''),
      $(this).parents("div.month").children('h4').html().replace(/\D/g, '')
    );
  });
});

function showData(a, b, c) {
  a = (a < 10) ? '0' + a : a;
  b = (b < 10) ? '0' + b : b;
  alert('Day:' + a + ', Month:' + b + ', Year:' + c);
}
$('#calendarTemplate').yacal();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://wxrunning.com/tests/jquery.yacal.css">

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://wxrunning.com/tests/jquery.yacal.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="calendarTemplate"></div>
```